# Amazon Cloud Drive Api Node api

Tags: java, forms, http

I was trying to upload a file to Amazon Cloud Drive using Android API   ([Link](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/experience/cloud-drive/content/nodes))

I am using AsyncHttpclient.
Below is  the code i have tried, but i did not ran sucessfully, I would like to know what is the correct parameter and header to set before making a post request.

I have already logged in and have token.

```
AsyncHttpClient cli = new AsyncHttpClient();

RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("kind","file");
params.put("name","img.jpg");

try{
params.put("file",new file(/sdcard/img));
}
catch(Exception e){
 }
 // other Request param to go here

chi.addHeader("Authorization: Bearer",authzToken);

chi.("content-na.drive.amazonaws.com/cdproxy/nodes", param,
new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                        Log.e("TaGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG", "" + statusCode);
                       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Possible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                   @Override
                   public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Your POST body needs to comply with the `multipart/form-data` format specified. There are two parts: "metadata" and "content". The kind and name must be put in the "metadata" part and the actual file content goes in the "content" section.

Update: Please google for a multipart form data encoder for Android.

Comment: Thanks but a couple of line of code would be really helpful like list of  params(Requestparams) before making post request.